# How to test if channel and queue are created and bind to the exchange in rabbitMq using rabbitMq TestContainer in Micronaut

Tags: java, rabbitmq, junit5, micronaut, micronaut-rabbitmq

At the start of the application, I am creating the below channel and associated queues

```
@Singleton
public class ChannelPoolListener extends ChannelInitializer {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Channel channel) throws IOException {
        channel.exchangeDeclare("micronaut", BuiltinExchangeType.DIRECT, true); 

        channel.queueDeclare("inventory", true, false, false, null); 
        channel.queueBind("inventory", "micronaut", "books.inventory"); 

        channel.queueDeclare("catalogue", true, false, false, null); 
        channel.queueBind("catalogue", "micronaut", "books.catalogue"); 
    }
}
```

I want to write the JUnit 5 test to check if queues are created and bind to the exchange using the rabbitMq Test container.

From the RabbitMq java API, I know we have a method for the channel. But not sure how can I inject the Channel in JUnit 5

```
GetResponse response = rabbitChannel.basicGet(QUEUE_NAME, BOOLEAN_NOACK);
```

Comment: "I want to write the JUnit 5 test to check if queues are created and bind to the exchange using the rabbitMq Test container" - Are you wanting to write a test that verifies those things in particular, or are you wanting your test to support your code that relies on those things?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am wanting to write a test that verifies those things in particular. For instance, the rabbitMq must contain the queue inventory and catalogue

Answer (score 0):

Just use the queue with a test client/subscriber via the Micronaut annotations or the java client API directly.

Comment: Can you please post a sample code with Micronaut annotations

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for this kind of result

```
@BeforeAll
    @DisplayName("Initial setup")
    void initialSetup() {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
             Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
            new ChannelPoolListener().initialize(channel);
            AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk response = channel.queueDeclarePassive("Hello world");
            Assertions.assertTrue(application.isRunning());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```